# auto-fill for new values in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google

I have a google spreadsheet that connected to the google form,
this form has the name, family name, email address and... questions.

I want my spreadsheet takes name and family name and combine them and put them in the desired column each time someone submits a form.

for example, I submit a form with name: ExampleOne, family name: ExampleTwo; this two value go to row 2, column A in sheet 1 and row2, column B in sheet 1
I want this to combine them and the spreadsheet put them together in row 2, column K.

I don't know js well so if you want to tell me a solution with the script, please write it with good details.

thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to copying this code into your Script editor, it should be configured as an [Installable `onFormSubmit` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

The code takes advantage of the [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit). The sequence of events is:

1. when the form response is submitted, the variable "newname" is created from the values of the response
2. the target range for Column K is defined. Note: the row number is obtained from the event objects.
3. the "newname" value is set into the target range.

---

```
function wa13510501(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Form Responses 1";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // DEBUG
  var newname = e.values[1]+" "+e.values[2];
  var namerange = sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),11);
  namerange.setValue(newname);
}
```